# How to structure a firestore database?

Tags: firebase, flutter, web, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I'm creating a flutter app with firestore ,stuck on data structure scenario. So the scenario is a user can visit multiple cities, I have 3000 cities and 100000 users and I wanna be able to add and query, which users have visited a particular city.
my current implementation is `users/userId/userDetails` and `cities/cityName/cityDetails`

Answer (score 0):

Given what little I've learned from the [video guides](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_hR4K4auoQ&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ) provided by Firebase; it depends on whether you just want to list the users (ie, just some basic information on them) that have visited a city; or, if what you want is to list users by the city/cities that they've visited.

For the first case, where you want to just list each city's visitors, you'd be better off creating a document that contains a list of visitors by their id. This would make it so that when you consult the cities, you don't have to retrieve the massive list of visitors every time you call it.

Alternatively, for the second scenario, you might want to do the reverse, where each user has a (sub) document containing the list of cities they've visited. This would be especially useful if the list of cities is expected to be particularly large, or if the userDetails file contains a lot of information about the user (lots of fields).
If the userDetails file doesn't contain a lot of details, more specifically if the amount of fields is rather small and you don't expect the user to visit more than, say, 150 cities, you could include it as one of the regular fields inside of userDetails, by setting it as an array (if you don't care about the order) or setting it as a Map (if you plan to have each city be a key, with the value pair being when the city was visited)

That being said, I'm advising this under the assumption that the implementation instructions that you've stated have the final entry be a document (cityDetails and userDetails), as it is was I believe makes the most sense (having the userId and the cityName as the collection).
If I've misunderstood your structure and it's actually "cities" as a document, "cityName" as a collection and "cityDetails" as a document; please let me know so I may fix my answer.